# how to check Logstash first character of field match with - or _ and replace it

Tags: logstash, grok

if in logstash field I have a field Kafka-topic-name
want to replace the first character if it matches _ or -

Comment: What do you want to replace it with?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I want to remove them if it is at starting of string so that I can use kafka topic name as elasticsearch index name